# Array_column an array_map return

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this array_map:

```php
    /* Return an array of _octopus_ids */
    $offices = array_map(
        function($post) {
            return array(
                'id' => get_post_meta($post->ID, '_octopus_id', true),
            );
        },
        $query->posts
    );
```

That returns the following:

```php
array (size=10)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '1382' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '1330' (length=4)
```

How can I implode that statement so I can get just the strings?

I've tried the following:

```php
    $test = implode(', ', $offices);
    var_dump($test);
```

The var_dump($test) returns the following: `Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array`.

I get the `Array to string conversion` error - What am I doing wrong? I'd love to just print out 1382 and then 1330

Comment: you're returning an `array`, just `return get_post_meta($post->ID, '_octopus_id', true);` result will be an array of strings.

Comment: @fyrye, I need to keep the id key for another reason later in the code.

Comment: please update your question to reflect your needs, right now it is phrased as a misunderstanding of how `array_map()` works. And why you need the `id` associative index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to fetch the array of all `id`

```
$offices = [
    ['id' => 1382],
    ['id' => 1330]
];

echo implode(', ', array_column($offices, 'id'));
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for which returns the strings in an array - Is there a way to grab just the strings without the array after using array_column?

Comment: @Sema see my answer

Comment: I have the following piece of code next `$results = $octopus->get_all('employees/' . implode(array_column($offices, 'id')));` and I'd like to have for example `employees/1382`. I'm getting an error with the following code.

Answer (score 2):

```
/* Return an array of _octopus_ids */
    $offices = array_map(
        function($post) {
            return get_post_meta($post->ID, '_octopus_id', true)
        },
        $query->posts
    );

    print_r($offices);

    //or

    $officesStr = implode(', ', $offices);
    echo $officesStr;

$useLaterArr = [];
foreach ($offices as $office) {
    $useLaterArr = ['id' => $office];
}

echo "For later use :)\n";
print_r($useLaterArr);

$another = ['id' => $offices];
echo "Another way:\n";
print_r($offices);
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Jimmix, but I need to keep the id key for another reason later in the code.

Comment: @Sema What id do you mean?

Comment: I need to store the _octopus_id's as an id array to match it later in the code, so I can't return just, I need to return it as an array of 'id's.

Comment: @Sema  after `implode()` it will be a comma separated string so what do you mean by `I need to return it as an array of 'id's.`???

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie, I guess the right thing that I was looking for was array_column.

Comment: @Jimmix, what’s the difference between using all that code and using array_column which worked - It's a legitimate question, I'm still learning.